# docker events filter healthchecks

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I discovered that there is a [docker events command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) which lists all events happening on the docker host.

I would like to use this on my CI to see any developer actions which will help me troubleshoot. Unfortunately each of my services has a healthcheck and each execution of the healthcheck is considered an event like the following:

> 2018-03-12T11:15:57.390800327+01:00 container exec_start: /bin/sh -c
>   check.sh
>   eb2676e25e747f77827490f5ded1c70051cd2a663746a5b0f458b46059258488
>   (com.docker.stack.namespace=proxy,
>   com.docker.swarm.node.id=g6zrzma1ua1etg5tbgvdoydz9,
>   com.docker.swarm.service.id=a12vrvs5m6vw9l1rrmzc82akb,
>   com.docker.swarm.service.name=proxy_proxy, com.docker.swarm.task=,
>   com.docker.swarm.task.id=nzjuh4uwsjb66u6m5j845zo21,
>   com.docker.swarm.task.name=proxy_proxy.1.nzjuh4uwsjb66u6m5j845zo21,
>   image=vfarcic/docker-flow-proxy:17.10.03-38@sha256:53caca880fbbcd8ed1cea9fc64b6c98e58ac9ca5d00ed0e630872b617ce33f41,
>   name=proxy_proxy.1.nzjuh4uwsjb66u6m5j845zo21)

different healthchecks have different commands but they all are exec_create or exec_start events. Is there a way to filter all those and just keep the rest of the events? Or maybe just keep events that are triggered by the CLI?

There is a filter functionality but I didn't find a way to exclude something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to exclude with current events CLI, but you could use grep to exclude:
`docker events | grep -v "container exec_"`